# Using a calendar table to interpolate values across a date range

Tags: mysql

**BACKGROUND**

I am working on a project where I need to capture the 30 day average of values for some id# then use this average to determine if some new value is anomalous. For the purposes of this question, we can assume I only need a 10-day average since the solutions are probably similar. I currently have two tables: `history` which holds the actual values that I have recorded for specific id# numbers by day but *can* have some missing days and `calendar` a date table that has all of the days that I need in my 30 day average.

```
create table history (
   day      date   not null, 
   id       bigint not null, 
   category int    not null,
   value    int    not null default '0',
   primary key (day, id, category),
   key category (category)
);

create table calendar (
   day date not null primary key
);
```

I would like to take the existing data that I have in the history table and fill in the missing data by either copying forward a previous value or copying back a forward value. E.g given this data in the history table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+
| day        | id        | category | value |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+
| 2015-02-19 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 |
| 2015-02-20 | 159253663 |    364   |   211 |
| 2015-02-22 | 159253663 |    364   |   199 |
| 2015-02-23 | 159253663 |    364   |   192 |
| 2015-02-24 | 159253663 |    364   |   213 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

*Note: there is no entry for 2015-02-21*

I would like to fill in enough data so that I can compute the 10-day average i.e. copy the oldest value (2015-02-19) back to the beginning of my 10-day range then fill in the missing 2015-02-21 value with the previous day's value. The result would be this (stars mark the newly added rows):

```
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+
| day        | id        | category | value |
+------------+-----------+----------+-------+
| 2015-02-14 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 | *
| 2015-02-15 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 | *
| 2015-02-16 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 | *
| 2015-02-17 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 | *
| 2015-02-18 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 | *
| 2015-02-19 | 159253663 |    364   |   212 |
| 2015-02-20 | 159253663 |    364   |   211 |
| 2015-02-21 | 159253663 |    364   |   211 | *
| 2015-02-22 | 159253663 |    364   |   199 |
| 2015-02-23 | 159253663 |    364   |   192 |
| 2015-02-24 | 159253663 |    364   |   213 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

**ATTEMPT**

My initial thought was to left join to a calendar table that has the date ranges I need, when I do that I get something like this:

```
select c.day, h.id, h.value
from calendar c 
   left join history h using (day)
where c.day between curdate() - interval 10 day and curdate();

+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| day        | id        | category |   value   |
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| 2015-02-14 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-15 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-16 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-17 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-18 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-19 | 159253663 |    364   |       212 |
| 2015-02-19 | 159253690 |    364   |       222 |
| 2015-02-20 | 159253663 |    364   |       211 |
| 2015-02-20 | 159253690 |    364   |       221 |
| 2015-02-21 |      NULL |   NULL   |      NULL |
| 2015-02-22 | 159253663 |    364   |       199 |
| 2015-02-22 | 159253690 |    364   |       209 |
| 2015-02-23 | 159253663 |    364   |       192 |
| 2015-02-23 | 159253690 |    364   |       202 |
| 2015-02-24 | 159253663 |    364   |       213 |
| 2015-02-24 | 159253690 |    364   |       213 |
+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

I am not sure where to proceed from this point, because I need an entry for each day for each distinct id#. This join only returns a single day if they are missing. I am looking for a better approach. I would like to push as much of the work as possible on the MySQL server, but can do some things programmaticaly. Any/all ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Here is a SQLFiddle that has the DDL definitions I am testing with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc206/2

Comment: "I would like to push as much of the work as possible on the MySQL server..." Is there any justification for this other than preference? It's usually a lot easier to fill in blanks within application code.

Comment: @tadman just preference, I will use whichever solution is the most efficient

Comment: The advantage of an application-side solution is you can do more sophisticated date calculations without having to depend on these computation tables being accurate. MySQL's procedural language can probably do this, but it's much harder to validate it as working correctly as there's no intrinsic test framework.

Comment: I see your point, most languages have access to a date library that is provable correct. The date table I am using is pretty well maintained though.

Comment: You're lucky then. I've often seen tables like this be the source of embarrassingly bad bugs, like missing Feb 29th on leap years or having 31 days in April for no particular reason.

Comment: The date table or application-side argument depends allot on your usage, I work with financial records from around the world, by using a date table I can grab dates from the source data that then automatically excludes holidays, weekends etc.

Comment: In SQL, the average of 212 and Null is 212. Is there a compelling reason to fabricate data rather than use SQL's normal behavior?

Comment: A requirement of this project is that if 30 days worth of data does not exist, use the earliest value for the missing days. Which affects the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses an @ variable and in-statement assignments to roll backward the value (and id):

```
SET @lastval = 0, @lastid = 0;
SELECT c.day, @lastid := COALESCE(h.id,@lastid) id,  @lastval := COALESCE(h.value,@lastval) VALUE, h.id id1,h.value v1
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.day,h.id FROM history h, calendar c) c
LEFT JOIN history h ON h.day = c.day AND h.id = c.id
WHERE c.day BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND CURDATE()
 ORDER BY COALESCE(h.id,@lastid),c.day DESC
```

The sub-query seems to be necessary, never been too sure why (some do, some don`t).

If it looks like the results are in the wrong order you might have to add :

```
SET optimizer_switch='block_nested_loop=off';
```

before the statement as the block nested loop optimisation can mess with the Order mysql uses when collecting the rows.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle multiple ids, it only copies back the first id through `2015-02-14`

Comment: @Hunter McMillen - not according to my results, I did have to edit it a bit, did you run the latest version.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I tried again (see latest edit, d`oh) - issue was with getting a full set of every date for each id. I think this looks right now.